# How to present images in one line instead of two using CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have the following code in a `wordpress` website that shows images:

```
 <div id="text-7" class="widget widget_text"><div class="inner-wrap clearfix">          <div class="textwidget"><p><center><img class="alignnone wp-image-956" src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/02-EU-2-300x218.png" alt="" width="85" height="62" />       <img class="alignnone wp-image-954" src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/03-Republic-of-Cyprus-300x245.png" alt="" width="77" height="62" />      <img class="alignnone wp-image-955" src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/04-ΔΤ-300x179.png" alt="" width="106" height="63" />   <img class="alignnone wp-image-884" src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/logo-ipe.png" alt="" width="117" height="51" />   <img class="alignnone wp-image-957" src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/cs-ucy-logo-300x66.jpg" alt="" width="203" height="44" /></center></p>
</div>
```

Now this content is not presented in one line: [image]

I need to edit the following `CSS` to fix this and present all the images in one line having center alignment.

```
#text-7  {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Where's the <img tag actually living? or is it a background-image? btw by default <divs> are "display:block" element, which by default gets rendered as a full block 100% wide, one per row

Comment: @Diego It's living under <div class="main-wrapper" id="main">

Comment: Do you have the site live? maybe you have something with float? try to add a <div> with CSS clear:both before the #text-7 div and see if it fix it

Comment: @Diego I added `display:flex;` and my problem fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

My `css` now is the following:

```
#text-7  {
    display:flex;
    width: 100%;
}
```